# Box2d in Xcode - use of undeclared identifier 'toDestroy'

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

Every tutorial I can find on Box2d says to do this to iterate through the bodies in a world:

```
    std::set<b2Body*>toDestroy; //ERROR

    for(b2Body *b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext()) {
        if (b->GetUserData() != NULL) {
            CCSprite *sprite = (__bridge CCSprite *)b->GetUserData();

            if (sprite.tag == kWhateverTag) {
                CCSprite *spriteData = (__bridge CCSprite *)b->GetUserData();
                spriteData.position = ccp(b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO,
                                        b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO);
                spriteData.rotation = -1 * CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(b->GetAngle());

                if (self.shouldDestroy) {
                    toDestroy.insert(b); //ERROR
                }

            }


        }    


    }
```

However I get the error `"Use of undeclared identifier 'toDestroy'; did you mean 'tgaDestroy'?`

What do I need to do to get rid of the error?

Answer (score 0):

This clears up the errors:

```
#import <vector>
#import <set>
#import <algorithm>
```